# Trying to Understand BEM

Tags: css, bem

So I am trying to understand the BEM naming structure. So lets say I have the following html

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner__toprow">
    <span class="banner__teamName">
        {{team.name}}
    </span>

    <span class="banner__score">
        {{team.score}}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="banner__timeouts">
        {{team.timeOuts}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now where I get confused is when you have nested divs, how that works. For example for `banner__teamName`, I would usually do `banner__toprow__teamName`. Now maybe I can do this, but does this break BEM?

Answer (score 4):

From the [BEM's FAQ](http://getbem.com/faq/)

> What would be a class name for an element inside another element? `.block__el1__el2?`
>
> According to BEM method, block structure should be flattened; you do
>   not need to reflect nested DOM structure of the block. So, the class
>   names for this case would be:

```
.block {}
.block__elem1 {}
.block__elem2 {}
.block__elem3 {}
```

Whereas the DOM representation of the block may be nested:

```
<div class='block'>
<div class='block__elem1'>
    <div class='block__elem2'>
        <div class='block__elem3'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides the fact that the classes look much nicer, it makes the elements be dependent on the block only. So, you can easily move them across the block when providing changes to the interface. The changes of the block DOM structure would not need corresponding changes to the CSS code.

```
<div class='block'>
<div class='block__elem1'>
    <div class='block__elem2'></div>
</div>
<div class='block__elem3'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest doing it like this:

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner__toprow">
    <span class="banner__toprow-teamname">
        {{team.name}}
    </span>

    <span class="banner__score">
        {{team.score}}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="banner__timeouts">
        {{team.timeOuts}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't believe it is correct to have two Elements (__) of Modifiers (--). I also try not to use camel case in my classes, that might be a personal preference but I feel it could cause problems with certain frameworks like Angular.